# kdb/q: use function in a select from partitioned table

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to get max drawdown from a partitioned table across multiple dates. The query works fine when run with a date constrained to a specific day. E.g.

```
select {max neg x-maxs x} pnl from trades where date=last date
```

It's getting map-reduced over multiple dates so the above query no longer works. I can make the query run over multiple dates by adding another aggregation:

```
select max {max neg x-maxs x} pnl from trades
```

but it's not getting the max drawdown from continuous sequence of trades but a maximum of daily drawdowns.

I wonder if there's a way to make it work with a single select without chaining selects like

```
select {max neg x-maxs x} pnl from select pnl from trades
```

I've got a rather big query to pull a lot of various metrics on the trades where max drawdown is just one of them. Using chained select means that I need to break the big query into two queries, map-reduced and non-map-reduced, and then join them back which would make the query look ugly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Select query runs on each date in partition db and apply function to each date values and finally aggregates them depending upon the call (user defined function behaves differently than plain 'q' functions).

So I don't think you can combine that into one query. But there are ways you can look for to make your query more generalized and reusable for different scenarios.

For ex. convert your query to functional form and use variables in that query for column name and user function. Put this in one function which will accept column name and user function. Now you can call this function with different set of (column ;function). Something like :

`runF:{[col;usrfunc] funtional_query_uses_col_userfunc }`

All this depends on your use cases. Also check for memory usage as you'll be taking lot of data into memory.